# Access class returned by function

Tags: php

Basically I have the following two functions

```
class Conversion
{
  public static function importAuthorization(array $authorization, int $main_dc_id, string $session, $settings) : \Generator
    {
        $settings = '...';       
        $MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API($session, $settings);
        return $MadelineProto;
    }


    public static function telethon(string $session, string $new_session, $settings = []) : \Generator
    {
        $dcs='...';
        return self::importAuthorization($dcs, $dc['dc_id'], $new_session, $settings);
    }
}
```

You can ignore the vars; Basically , when I do the following:

`$mad = $import->telethon('xx','xx')->getSelf();`

will return

`Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Generator::getSelf()`.

`getSelf()` function is a method of `\danog\MadelineProto\API` class which is returned by importAuthorization().

How can I properly call the function on the object returned by importAuthorization?

Thank you!!

Comment: Please add getSelf() method code

Comment: You've told the code that the `telethon` function will return a class of type `Generator`, but then it actually returns a class of type `API`. No wonder it's confused, don't you think?

Comment: Although possibly something else is also going on, because I tried to mock this situation and I don't quite get the same error as you - I actually get one which gives a better explanation of the problem: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bf373144f908b1c4ef816b2030919b1b0d183191 . Please update the question to provide a [mre] of the issue, so we can diagnose it properly. Either way though, it really makes no sense to declare that you're going to return one thing, and then return something completely different...that's at the root of your issue.